# How could I get two urls by the same request in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, request

I want to get the contents of 'a.com/a.html' and 'a.com/b.html' with the same request
And my code is

```
uri = URI.parse("http://www.sample.com/sample1.html")  
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)  
request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)  
# request.initialize_http_header({"User-Agent" => "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X     10_8_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.95 Safari/537.36"}) 
result = http.request(request).body
```

should i change the path of the request?or any other idea?

Comment: Just out of curiosity: why?

Comment: You simple can't get 2 pages via one request. Why not use 2 requests and merge the content together?

Answer (score 0):

You can't fetch multiple resources at once, but you can reuse a HTTP connection to fetch multiple resources from the same server (one after another):

```
require 'net/http'

Net::HTTP.start('a.com') do |http|
  result_a = http.get('/a.html').body
  result_b = http.get('/b.html').body
end
```

From the [docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#label-How+to+use+Net%3A%3AHTTP):

> `::start` immediately creates a connection to an HTTP server which is kept open for the duration of the block. The connection will remain open for multiple requests in the block if the server indicates it supports persistent connections.